# Disable Phone Number in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I had a Question on Firebase Phone Auth. When a user Logs In using the OTP, the Phone numbers can be seen in the firebase console. In this List of Phone Numbers, on the right there is option to either Disable Account or Delete Account. I wanted to know what would happen if I Disable an Account(Phone No). will it Logout the User if he's logged In ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you disable an account, the following 2 behaviors are observed:

1. If a user tries to sign-in after, they will an error indicator the user is disabled.
2. If a user is already signed in, the next time the token refreshes (token has 1 hour lifetime), the operation will fail and the user is automatically signed out. Also if the user tries to update the account (before expiration), such as updating profile, linking/unlinking a provider, the operation fails and the user is automatically signed out.